# Cant create cookies when website is online

Tags: php, cookies

when i try to create a cookie with PHP they are not saved when the website is online.
When i'm on the localhost, its all okay.

For example:

```
setcookie('user_register', 'username', time() + 3600, '/');
```

How can i troubleshoot this? Is there any config in cpanel to disable cookie creation ?

Thankyou

Comment: Can you post the full code? Do you have any output before the setcookie? That will make it not work. Always have setcookie as high up as possible in the code

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say it works on localhost, which alerts me to think that you have placed the setcookie below output like this for example:

```
<?php
// top of file
Echo "saving cookie";
setcookie('user', 'username', 3600, '/');
?>
```

This may work on localhost but will always fail on a real php server.
Setcookie is a `header` and must be placed before any output as stated in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

To make the code above work you need to chaange place of the echo and setcookie so that it first sets the cookie and then outputs the text:

```
<?php
// top of file
setcookie('user', 'username', 3600, '/');
Echo "saving cookie";
?>
```

Then to read the cookie you need to go to a new page or refresh the page.
Cookies can't be set and read at the same time in php.
So to complete the code we can do like this:

```
<?php
// top of file
If($_COOKIE(['user']){     
   Echo $_COOKIE(['user']);
}Else{
   setcookie('user', 'username', 3600, '/');
   Echo "saving cookie";
}
?>
```

Now you can set the cookie and read it on the same page if you refresh the page.

Comment: That was the problem. I forgot i couldn't output before setting a cookie. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are used next time you visit the page. So there are 3 general solutions: 1. Save it to cookie and for first time, just echo POST variables instead of COOKIE. Code will look like this:

```
setcookie('user', $_POST['user'], time()+3600); // notice time() function
setcookie('pass', $_POST['pass'], time()+3600); // you cant use absolute value here

if (!isset($_COOKIE['user'])) echo $_POST['user'] . ' ' . $_POST['pass'];
    else echo $_COOKIE['user'] . ' ' . $_COOKIE['pass'];
```

, but if you really want to store password in cookie (very bad idea), then at least hash it. Code with hashing could look like this:

```
setcookie('pass', hash(whirlpool/*algorithm*/, $_POST['pass']/*text*/), time()+3600);
```

, then when you check the password, just hash it and compare hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send and receive cookie in the same request. Here is a modification you should try

```
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){

setcookie("user",$_POST['user'],3600);
setcookie("pass",$_POST['pass'],3600);

header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

}
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']) && isset($_COOKIE['user']))
{
echo $_COOKIE["user"] . " " . $_COOKIE["pass"];  // This is line 28

}
```

However, it advisable to use sessions instead. Start by going through [PHP_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)